# Mysql INSERT INTO UNION run out of memory

Tags: mysql

I have 8 large databases which i'd like to join in one. 
Therefore i use

```
INSERT INTO database (SELECT 0 ...) UNION (SELECT 1 ...) UNION (SELECT 2 ...)
```

with some CONCAT statements. I recreate this database once each day.

Sometimes, after a a week, mysql returns "error 5 out of memory need to allocate 16777...bytes".

I have only 3 GB total available in server.

Comment: By "databases" you mean tables right ? Otherwise, `INSERT INTO` doesn't work too well on DB.

Comment: Show your actual query.

Comment: Each single INSERT needs much more time - in fact the UNION runs in about 30 sec. (when enough memory) otherwise each select runs forever ...

Comment: Why the union and not separate inserts? I think the `union` means your complete table will be made as a temporary table, and then inserted. There;s no need for that I think. Furthermore, your question is a bit sparse. There is, for instance, no question in there.

Comment: Sorry for my cryptic question - i try it again. USING the UNION will run in about 20 sek. while memory is enough. But, when splitting into separate INSERT IGNORE INTO ... it will run forever. So it looks like mysql has gone...

Comment: Not sure what's asked here, but I would suggest analyzing/repairing tables, this error message can be thrown on corrupted data.